# is necessary to protect the update and delete routes?

Tags: node.js, routes, middleware

I am programming some middlewares in nodejs, and I was wondering if it is necessary to protect the update and delete routes, since I have already protect get and put route to create elements, the user doesn't have access to other elements than theirs. This is the get route:

```
router.get('/notes', [verifyAuth], async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.user._id
  try {
    const notesDB = await Note.find({ userId })
    return res.status(200).json(notesDB)
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'An error ocurred on the server',
      error
    })
  }
})
```

In this way, the user only has access to their notes and it is not necessary to protect the routes to avoid him from delete other user's notes. But do i need to do it anyway? it is a best practice?

Comment: If id values are guessable in any way, you should protect update and delete.  That would depend partially on what record identifiers you use in your URLs for update and delete.

Comment: Yes and only yes. Delete and Edit are very sensitive in every app.

Answer (score 1):

You should protect the `put` and `delete` routes. Even if there is no UI for the user to interact with these routes, one can use tools like Postman to send HTTP requests to these endpoints. Since you are not protecting them, the request will get through and the action will be executed. It might lead to some unwanted behaviors, such as the database being updated with arbitrary values or important data being deleted.